# How do I prevent PowerCharts from truncating axis labels?

Tags: truncate, fusioncharts, clip

In the Flash version of PowerCharts' ErrorLine chart, the rightmost X axis label is clipped if there are too many categories in the chart. Is there a way to stop PowerCharts from clipping the rightmost X axis label, or is this a bug in PowerCharts?

The following is an example XML that will reproduce the issue I am having when coupled with an ErrorLine of 700x480 pixels:

```
<chart caption="An example graph" xAxisName="X Axis" yAxisName="Y Axis" showValues="0" >
  <categories>
    <category label="0" />  <category label="1" />  <category label="2" />  <category label="3" />  <category label="4" />
    <category label="5" />  <category label="6" />  <category label="7" />  <category label="8" />  <category label="9" />
    <category label="10" /> <category label="11" /> <category label="12" /> <category label="13" /> <category label="14" />
    <category label="15" /> <category label="16" /> <category label="17" /> <category label="18" /> <category label="19" />
    <category label="20" /> <category label="21" /> <category label="22" /> <category label="23" /> <category label="24" />
    <category label="25" /> <category label="26" /> <category label="27" /> <category label="28" /> <category label="29" />
    <category label="30" /> <category label="31" /> <category label="32" /> <category label="33" />
  </categories>
  <dataset seriesName="A">
    <set value="0" />   <set value="0" />   <set value="1" />   <set value="2" />   <set value="4" />
    <set value="8" />   <set value="16" />  <set value="32" />  <set value="64" />  <set value="128" />
    <set value="192" /> <set value="224" /> <set value="240" /> <set value="248" /> <set value="252" />
    <set value="254" /> <set value="255" /> <set value="255" /> <set value="254" /> <set value="252" />
    <set value="248" /> <set value="240" /> <set value="224" /> <set value="192" /> <set value="128" />
    <set value="64" />  <set value="32" />  <set value="16" />  <set value="8" />   <set value="4" />
    <set value="2" />   <set value="1" />   <set value="0" />   <set value="0" />
  </dataset>
</chart>
```

And just for good measure, here's the HTML I used to set up the chart:

```
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var testChart = new FusionCharts( "ErrorLine.swf", "testChartId", "700", "480", "0", "1" );
  testChart.setXMLUrl("_Truncation.xml");
  testChart.render("chartContainer");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is fixed in the latest version. Try once upgrading to the latest release and check.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice this because my browser was caching the old version of the swf file.